# getting error while executing runnodes command on mac

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am facing problem while setting up cordapp example on a mac machine.
When i am executing command for runnodes i am facing below issues.

> ⚠️   ATTENTION: This node is running in development mode! ‍   This
>   is not safe for production deployment. Advertised P2P messaging
>   addresses      : localhost:10012 RPC connection address
>   : localhost:10013 RPC admin connection address            :
>   localhost:10051 [ERROR] 15:11:58+0530 [main] core.server.run -
>   AMQ224000: Failure in initialisation [errorCode=1i0luyg,
>   moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/1i0luyg] Shutting
>   down ... [ERROR] 15:11:58+0530 [main] core.server.stop - AMQ224028:
>   Failed to stop acceptor 33d8136b-61be-11e9-bea4-acde48001122 [ERROR]
>   15:11:58+0530 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Exception
>   during node startup: failed to create a child event loop
>   [errorCode=1i0luyg,
>   moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/1i0luyg]

Answer (score 0):

AMQP is failing to initialise. This is usually because some other process (e.g. a zombie Corda node) is holding the port that AMQP wants to use.

Try killing the process listening on that port and running the nodes again.